# Display images via HTTP links on HTTPS page in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, https

I have a page that shows the favicon.ico in links to several other sites.

My page uses HTTPS, but some of the sites that hose the favicon.ico files are HTTP.

It appears Microsoft Edge, at least, won't display those HTTP resources on an HTTPS page.

It's not practical for me to change all those websites to use HTTPS. And it's kind of important for me to display those icons.

Has anyone found a workaround for this? I know there are questions posted about this, but none of those that offer solutions are using ASP.NET core.

Comment: If it's just favicon images, could you perhaps proxy those requests through your server (i.e. request is made to your application, your application makes request to remote site, serves favicon)?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: Hmm... good idea. I can try to explore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ProgrammingLlama suggested, I created a proxy to load these icons.

To do this, I created a Razor Pages page handler.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetFavIconAsync([FromServices] IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, string url)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return File(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), "image/x-icon");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    return File("/Images/NoIcon.png", "image/png");
}
```

And then I referenced the handler from my markup.

```
<a href="@website.Url">
    <img src="@Url.Page("Index", "FavIcon", new { url = website.IconUrl } )" alt="@website.Title" title="@website.Title"
        style="width: 32px; height: 32px" />
</a>
```

Comment: My only suggestion is to perhaps pass something like the website id (presumably that's how you generate your page) rather than the URL itself, or perhaps validate the URL before making the request. At the moment I just worry that a) this can be used to make arbitrary GET requests beyond what you intended and b) a malicious user could point this at a large file and use it as a kind of DoS attack vector. That's my 2 cents anyway.